# Laravel не отдаёт изображения (спрайты)

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

Есть простенькие скрипты на JS, которые работают со спрайтами (jpg). Дебажил их отдельно от laravel, всё работает прекрасно... Решил закинуть их в свой проект, скрипты подключил и все нужные спрайты закинул в public (laravel) пример пути:

```
public/xxx/sprites/*.jpg
```

Но, браузер выдаёт ошибки, js/css не могут найти их по заданным пути (404)

Comment: а путь то какой указываете яваскрипту?

Comment: используйте `aseet();`